# Excel table loses number formats when data is copied from ADODB recordset

Tags: vba, excel, adodb

I'm updating an excel table from an **ADODB** recordset using the `CopyFromRecordset` method.

After the update, the numbers show up as dates wherever there are number columns.

The workaround I used until now is to format the columns back to numbers through **VBA**, but it's not a good solution as takes more time for the report to complete. Also I have to write code to accommodate a lot of tables.

Is there a quick fix? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
'Delete old data and copy the recordset to the table
Me.ListObjects(tblName).DataBodyRange.ClearContents
Me.Range(tblName).CopyFromRecordset rst
```

`tblName` - refers to an existing table that held data of the same format/datatype as rst data

Comment: Try this `Me.Range(tblName).Columns(1).Numberformat = "0"` before exporting the data using `CopyFromRecordset` Where `1` for example is the relevant column which has the numbers stored.

Comment: I'm currently doing this to each number column (or range of columns where possible) after the data import. Doing it before the import just changes the timing, but does not solve the problem. I would still have to write code to fix every number column in every table. I would like the table to keep the formats as they were before the import.

Comment: There are no 'formats' in an ADODB recordset, only Datatypes. You can alter your code to automatically set the Excel format based on a columns ADODB datatype, but there are no formats inherently in an ADODB dataset - take a look at all the properties in it.

Comment: @ElectricLlama By 'formats' I meant the column formats in the existing excel table. I was not referring to the datatypes of the fields in the ADODB recordset. For example, columns formatted as numbers in the excel table become columns formatted as dates after the copyFromRecordset is executed.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a late answer, but I was encountering this same error. I think I've found a workaround.

It seems Excel expects the range to be the top-left cell rather than a range of cells. So just modify your statement to `Range(tblName).Cells(1,1).CopyFromRecordset rst`

```
'Delete old data and copy the recordset to the table
Me.ListObjects(tblName).DataBodyRange.ClearContents
Me.Range(tblName).Cells(1,1).CopyFromRecordset rst
```

There also seems to be a requirement that the target sheet be active, so you *might* have to ensure the sheet is active first, and then change back to the previously active sheet. This might have been fixed in later version of Excel.

Comment: `.Cells(1, 1)` is a great solution! Works

Answer (score 2):

Try this - this copies resultset into a array, transposes it and then copies it into excel

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

Dim targetRange As Excel.Range

Dim vDat As Variant

' Set rs

' Set targetRange   

rs.MoveFirst

vDat = Transpose(rs.GetRows)

targetRange.Value = vDat


Function Transpose(v As Variant) As Variant
    Dim X As Long, Y As Long
    Dim tempArray As Variant

    ReDim tempArray(LBound(v, 2) To UBound(v, 2), LBound(v, 1) To UBound(v, 1))
    For X = LBound(v, 2) To UBound(v, 2)
        For Y = LBound(v, 1) To UBound(v, 1)
            tempArray(X, Y) = v(Y, X)
        Next Y
    Next X

    Transpose = tempArray

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is sample code. Whenever the proc getTableData is called the formatting & column format of the table1 will be retained according to the recordset. I hope this is what you are looking for.

```
 Sub getTableData()

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = getRecordset

    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Clear
    Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
    Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("A1").CurrentRegion, , xlNo).Name = "Table1"

End Sub



Function getRecordset() As ADODB.Recordset

    Dim rsContacts As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rsContacts = New ADODB.Recordset

    With rsContacts
        .Fields.Append "P_Name", adVarChar, 50
        .Fields.Append "ContactID", adInteger
        .Fields.Append "Sales", adDouble
        .Fields.Append "DOB", adDate
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .CursorType = adOpenStatic

        .Open

        For i = 1 To WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(3, 5)
             .AddNew
            !P_Name = "Santosh"
            !ContactID = 2123456 * i
            !Sales = 10000000 * i
            !DOB = #4/1/2013#
            .Update
        Next

        rsContacts.MoveFirst
    End With

    Set getRecordset = rsContacts
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your sample code. However I have formulas referencing my tables by so I cannot delete the tables (your `Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Clear` deletes the table entirely). I have to reuse the tables otherwise all my formulas would have `'#REF!'` errors. The problem where numbers get formatted as dates happens after I clear the table of the old data (`Me.ListObjects(tblName).DataBodyRange.ClearContents`) and copy the new data from the recordset back to the same table (`Me.Range(tblName).CopyFromRecordset rst`).

Answer (score 0):

After reading through forums posts of other people who encountered the same problem, here are all the options I know of (some of them already mentioned in other answers):

1. Insert only into the first cell of the target range - see @ThunderFrame's answer.
2. Activate worksheet that contains target range on the line above `CopyFromRecordset()`
3. Turn off automatic recalculation:

   ```
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   .CopyFromRecordset rs
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   ```

Workarounds:

1. Iterate rows/columns and insert values one at a time - @Sriketan's answer provides code for this one. Another code snippets are in the links below.
2. Paste into temporary workbook and then copy it from there.

Sources:

1. Duchgemini's post and discussion: https://dutchgemini.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/two-serious-flaws-with-excels-copyfromrecordset-method/
2. Microsoft's forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/129c0a52-4ccb-4f54-9e38-8c0ae6e300b1/copyfromrecordset-corrupts-cell-formats-for-the-whole-excel-workbook?forum=exceldev