# ADODB Excel Database - Date Format Issue

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently using the below script below to retrieve data from another Excel workbook.  I retrieve the proper date in proper format.  The problem occurs when the workbook that i am querying is "OPEN" the retrieved data "DATE" returns a NUMBER "49802"(something like that) but as soon as i close the workbook that i am querying the returned "DATE" become normal format.

```
Sub Pull_Data_from_Excel_with_ADODB()

Dim cnStr As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim query As String
Dim var1
Dim var2
var1 = Now() - 1
var2 = Now()
Dim fileName As String
fileName = "C:\Signin-Database\DATABASE\Signin-Database.xlsm"

cnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
       "Data Source=" & fileName & ";" & _
       "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0"


query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$D:H] WHERE [Time_in] < '" & var2 & "' AND [Time_in] >  '" & var1 & "' AND [Time_out] is null"

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open query, cnStr, adOpenUnspecified, adLockUnspecified

Cells.Clear
Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

Dim Cell As Range, i As Long
With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    .Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rs.Fields(i).Name
Next i
.EntireColumn.AutoFit





End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Try closing your recordset and see if that "makes" the dates changes to what they should be.

After you autofit command

```
.EntireColumn.AutoFit
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

If that doesn't work, try formatting the columns that have a date.

```
ws.Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
ws.Range("E:E").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
```

If you have a header row and you want to not format that you can define start and end rows in your range

```
Dim lRow as Long
lRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.count

ws.Range("A2:A" & lRow).NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
ws.Range("E2:E" & lRow).NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel stores its date values as a number- the integral part is the number of days counting up from January 1900, and the fractional part is the hours.  So for example, 49802.25 would be 5/7/2036 at 6am.  So, the issue is likely due to cell formatting which could be corrupted by the .CopyFromRecordSet method.  I have had this problem in a few of my workbooks too, where if it is pulling a date field from Sql it will affect the cell formatting on other worksheets.

[Excel table loses number formats when data is copied from ADODB recordset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070313/excel-table-loses-number-formats-when-data-is-copied-from-adodb-recordset)

https://dutchgemini.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/two-serious-flaws-with-excels-copyfromrecordset-method/
(flaw #2 on this one)

One workaround that worked for me is to have your macro format the effected cells back to the correct format, which can be done using the .NumberFormat method.

[What are .NumberFormat Options In Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648149/what-are-numberformat-options-in-excel-vba)