# Excel ADODB Query Dates

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to Query Excel Column for Dates ( for example this is Jul, then only retrieve Jul dates from column) I have tried to declared a current month and previous month but still am unable to retrieve data.  I have tried to format query sheet as (m/d/yyyy) multiple formats to match query but still no luck. please any help much appreciated here is the code below

```
Dim cnStr As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim query As String
Dim var1
Dim var2
Dim fileName As String
Dim CurrMonth As String, PrevMonth As String
CurrMonth = Format$(Date, "m/d/yyyy")
PrevMonth = Format$(Date - Day(Date), "m/d/yyyy")
fileName = "**********\DB1.xlsm"

    cnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
           "Data Source=" & fileName & ";" & _
           "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0"

query = "SELECT * FROM [test1$A:B] WHERE [test]>'" & PrevMonth & "' AND [test]<'" & CurrMonth & "'"
```

Comment: This question has an answer that gives some information on how excel stores dates. It may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31492086/adodb-excel-database-date-format-issue/31492716#31492716

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a between conditional operator.  And use the pound signs.

```
BETWEEN #7/1/2008# And #7/31/2008#

query = "SELECT * FROM [test1$A:B] WHERE [test] BETWEEN #" & PrevMonth & "# And #" & CurrMonth & "#"
```

Comment: That did the trick, another way i found to work was to format query worksheet column to custom text and then setup my calendar control to format as text(7-17-2015). I like MatthewD way better, thanks a great deal, 2 days of trial and error, should have posted 2 days ago then trial and error..lol thanks again

Comment: Glad we got it worked out. There are always many ways to do it. Keep coding.